# Hibernate Criteria to match against all child collection

Tags: hibernate

I have a hibernate many to many relationship between Product and Tag
Product class has a 'tags' collection Set as per many to many mapping
I am trying to fetch  the products which matches all the tags (not any of the tags)
the following will fetch all products which matches any of the tag.

```
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Product.class,"Prdct");  
   crit.createAlias("Prdct.tags","PT");  
crit.add(Restrictions.in("PT.Name",selectedTags));  
crit.list();
```

how to do this using criteria?

Comment: Do you mean that all the selected tags should be present in the product tags? Or that all the product tags should be present in the selected tags? Or that both sets should contain exactly the same tags?

Comment: I guess this is to find Products tagged with every one of a small set of search tags, based on a large set of available tags. E.g., find all shirts with tags "cotton" and "long-sleeve", ignore whether tag "sale" is present.

Answer (score 1):

its only useful for sets

```
// get the count of tags matching the criteria
DetachedCriteria subquery = DetachedCriteria.For(Product.class)
    .add(Expression.eq("id","product.id"))
    .createAlias("tags","tag")  
    .add(Restrictions.in("tag.Name", selectedTags))
    .setProjection(Projections.count("PT.Name"));

// get the Products where there all tags match
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Product.class,"product")
    .add(Subqueries.eq(selectedTags.getCount(), subquery);
```

Comment: This uses alias "PT" but that's only defined in the questioner's code. I posted a very very closely related question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51992269/hibernate-java-criteria-query-for-instances-with-multiple-collection-members-lik